# Visual Studio 2008 + embedded web server on Windows Vista

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-vista

OS: Windows Vista Business SP1

IDE: Visual Studio 2008 SP1

Question: when I create a new web application in VS 2008 and start it, the embedded web server from VS 2008 launches on one port (say 50140). Then the browser (IE7) automatically launches with address http://localhost:50137/..., note the different port number. Obviously, there is nothing on IE-requested port. What should I do to have IE launching on the same port as the server launches on? For Windowx XP, this problem does not occur...

Answer (score 1):

You could check the web launch options in the project properties. It may be hard coded to load a specific URL - maybe from a previous run.

Comment: The "use dynamic port" is set to "true".

Comment: Under start action (Properties->Web) is there's a specific page being set?

Comment: I know this sounds silly, but have you tried restarting VS/ your PC. Or setting a new default browser (FF/ Chrome) via the Right Mouse Click option on a form to see if it still does it...

Comment: Restart VS: no change, excepting the port number - but the same stupid behavior. Restart PC - not tried yet, but surely this is not an option. With FF as default browser everything went ok.

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you make the port a fixed value rather than dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have multiple projects in the solution, one of them must be a web service, and the other (In IE) is a Web application.

Comment: No, there is a single project in the solution - the web project.